# Twisted cochain as a model for universal cover

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a pointed connected cw-complex and $C_{\ast}(X)$ the singular chain complex associated to $X$.
Let denote $G=\pi_{1}(X)$ and $\tilde{X}$ the universal covering space for $X$.
As far as I understand there is a twist $\tau: C_{\ast}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}G[1]$ i.e. a chain map (of degree $-1$) from $C_{\ast}(X)$ to $\mathbb{Z}G$ verifying the Maurer–Cartan equation such that the twisted chain complex $C_{\ast}(X)\otimes_{\tau}\mathbb{Z}G$ is quasi-isomorphic to $C_{\ast}(\tilde{X})$. I was wondering if there is a concrete description of the twist $\tau$? Moreover can we construct it in a natural (functorial) way?

Comment: Isn't it simply the construction where you chose for each 0-cell x a path p_x to the base point, and then for each 1-cell v:x->y, you get an element of $\pi_1$ by composing $v$ with $p_y$ and $(p_x)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @SimonHenry that was my guess, i did not verify the MC equation do you ?.  It shows that this map is not natural, since as you noticed we have to make a choice.

Comment: If you want naturality one could opt to use reduced chains, i.e. singular simplices where all vertices are the base point. For a connected space, basic arguments about homotopy extension imply that the inclusion of reduced chains into chains is a quasi-isomorphism (think of cycles as maps from a simplicial complex and pick paths from the vertices to the base point and extend etc.). Then with this chain complex the map from the edges to $\pi_1(X)$ is just the identity.

Answer (score -2):

A general context for this question which also deals with the non connected and non pointed cases,  is in  the book [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://groupoids.org.uk/nonabtens.html),  Section 8.4 of Part II. The book  discusses a homotopically defined functor $\Pi$ from *filtered spaces*  to the so-called *crossed complexes*, used under other names by A.L.  Blakers (1948) and by J.H.C. Whitehead (1949) in the connected case,  and another functor $\nabla$ from  crossed complexes to *chain complexes with a groupoid of operators*. The Relative Hurewicz Theorem (proved in the previous section in the crossed complex context) gives the result you want.

These constructions are functorial, and  the Relative Hurewicz Theorem is proved as a Corollary of a Higher Order Seifert-Van Kampen Theorem proved in Part III, together with the fact that $\nabla $ has a right adjoint.